# Include Hyperlinks in copied data using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code which copies the data from one tab to another which is also serves like a lookup function. It works well in copying the data, but in the source tab, there are hyperlinks, using the script that I have only copies the data and excluding the hyperlinks.

```
function doLookup2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const wsTarget = ss.getSheetByName("week 2");
  const wsSource = ss.getSheetByName("week 1");

  const sourceDataRange = wsSource.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1); // exclude header row
  const targetDataRange = wsTarget.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1); // exclude header row

  const nonBlankTargetDataRange = targetDataRange.filter(row => row[0] !== ""); // exclude rows where column B is blank

  const matchData = nonBlankTargetDataRange.map(targetRow => {
    const matchRow = sourceDataRange.find(sourceRow => sourceRow[0] == targetRow[0] && sourceRow[1] == targetRow[1]);
    return matchRow ? matchRow.slice(10, 45) : [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];
  });
  
  wsTarget.getRange(2, 11, matchData.length, 35).setValues(matchData);

  deleteNameWeek2();
}
```

I have seen something about the getRichTextValues(), but I am getting an error:

> Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property setRichTextValues on object SpreadsheetApp.Range.

and I am totally no idea how it works.

Comment: Can you share a minimum reproducible example of your sheet so we can see how your data works? Also in your example code, I think that you have also provided a code where the getRichTextValues() is not being used. By providing this information that community will have a better chance of helping  you with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your showing script, I thought that your script copies only values. Unfortunately, the cell and text formats are not copied. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.
- And, from your script, the continuous rows are not used and the rows which are not copied might be required to be kept. I thought that in this situation when the rows are copied including the cell and text formats to only the specific rows, your goal might be able to be simply achieved. In this case, I thought that the Sheets API might be useful.

In this modification, I would like to propose using Sheets API for your script. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And please confirm your sheet names again.

```js
function doLookup2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const wsTarget = ss.getSheetByName("week 2");
  const wsSource = ss.getSheetByName("week 1");
  const srcSheetId = wsSource.getSheetId();
  const dstSheetId = wsTarget.getSheetId();
  const sourceDataRange = wsSource.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
  const targetDataRange = wsTarget.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
  const obj = new Map(sourceDataRange.map((r, i) => [`${r[0]}${r[1]}`, i]));
  const requests = targetDataRange.reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    const k = `${r[0]}${r[1]}`
    if (obj.has(k)) {
      const row = obj.get(k);
      const columnRange = { startColumnIndex: 10, endColumnIndex: 45 };
      ar.push({
        copyPaste: {
          source: { sheetId: srcSheetId, startRowIndex: row + 1, endRowIndex: row + 2, ...columnRange },
          destination: { sheetId: dstSheetId, startRowIndex: i + 1, endRowIndex: i + 2, ...columnRange },
          pasteType: "PASTE_NORMAL"
        }
      });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (requests.length > 0) Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());

  deleteNameWeek2();
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of "K:AS" matched by columns "A" and "B" of "week 1" and "week 2" sheets are copied from the source sheet to the destination sheet.

#### Note:

- I'm not sure about your `deleteNameWeek2()`. So, this modified script supposes that your `deleteNameWeek2()` works. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [CopyPasteRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#copypasterequest)

Comment: Hey! It works! thank you very much! 

deleteNameWeek2() is just a separate function which deletes all  the names in all of name columns and doesn't directly affect the main script