# How to import column data from one sheet to the other sheet that still remain the format of the content in cell in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to import data from source sheet to the destination sheet, but when my data have more than 1 hyperlink, it will not clickable in the destination sheet ( example in cell O13 which imported from E3 on the right side ), the output i want is it will remain the content and also the format of its when imported, link to test

source sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mhYemGjgoRJDb7drNN36g7MuNDDmynR3v6l3kgn8da8/edit#gid=0

destination sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kN4IEShs-NB3EDBgmeonXm1hNgs48bBEPOVpBK3D6OE/edit?usp=sharing
[image]

Comment: i put the link sheet to test here, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mhYemGjgoRJDb7drNN36g7MuNDDmynR3v6l3kgn8da8/edit#gid=0,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include Hyperlinks in copied data using google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76622246/include-hyperlinks-in-copied-data-using-google-app-script)

Comment: thanks for reference, i will consider it and reply you later

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you run this script, please set the variables in your situation.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const srcSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set source spreadsheet ID.
  const dstSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set destination spreadsheet ID.
  const srcSheetName = "S1"; // Please set source sheet name.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set destination sheet name.

  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = [{ id: srcSpreadsheetId, sheetName: srcSheetName }, { id: dstSpreadsheetId, sheetName: dstSheetName }].map(({ id, sheetName }) => SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetName));
  const srcRange = srcSheet.getDataRange();
  const srcValues = srcRange.getValues();
  const srcRichTextValues = srcRange.getRichTextValues().map((r, i) =>
    r.map((c, j) => isNaN(srcValues[i][j]) ? c : SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(srcValues[i][j]).build())
  );
  dstSheet.getRange(srcRange.getA1Notation()).setRichTextValues(srcRichTextValues);
}
```

- When this script is run, the rich text values of the source sheet in the source Spreadsheet are copied to the destination sheet in the destination Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added 1:

About your following additional request

> how can i specify the column to get range data in source sheet and column to recieve data in destination sheet

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const srcSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set source spreadsheet ID.
  const dstSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set destination spreadsheet ID.
  const srcSheetName = "S1"; // Please set source sheet name.
  const srcRangeA1Notation = "A1:A"; // Please set source range as A1Notation.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set destination sheet name.

  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = [{ id: srcSpreadsheetId, sheetName: srcSheetName }, { id: dstSpreadsheetId, sheetName: dstSheetName }].map(({ id, sheetName }) => SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetName));
  const srcRange = srcSheetName ? srcSheet.getRange(srcRangeA1Notation) : srcSheet.getDataRange();
  const srcValues = srcRange.getValues();
  const srcRichTextValues = srcRange.getRichTextValues().map((r, i) =>
    r.map((c, j) => isNaN(srcValues[i][j]) ? c : SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(srcValues[i][j]).build())
  );
  dstSheet.getRange(srcRange.getA1Notation()).setRichTextValues(srcRichTextValues);
  // or dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, srcRichTextValues.length, srcRichTextValues[0].length).setRichTextValues(srcRichTextValues);
}
```

### Added 2:

About your following reply

> but the added script just have the range of source column, which line of script contain the range of destination column

> example: i want import data in range column A ( A1:A ) into column range B (B1:B), just reply me if you still confuse

Is your expected script as follows? In this case, column "A" of the source sheet is copied to column "B" of the destination sheet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const srcSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set source spreadsheet ID.
  const dstSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set destination spreadsheet ID.
  const srcSheetName = "S1"; // Please set source sheet name.
  const srcRangeA1Notation = "A1:A"; // Please set source range as A1Notation.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set destination sheet name.
  const dstColumn = 2; // Column "B"

  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = [{ id: srcSpreadsheetId, sheetName: srcSheetName }, { id: dstSpreadsheetId, sheetName: dstSheetName }].map(({ id, sheetName }) => SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetName));
  const srcRange = srcSheetName ? srcSheet.getRange(srcRangeA1Notation) : srcSheet.getDataRange();
  const srcValues = srcRange.getValues();
  const srcRichTextValues = srcRange.getRichTextValues().map((r, i) =>
    r.map((c, j) => isNaN(srcValues[i][j]) ? c : SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(srcValues[i][j]).build())
  );
  dstSheet.getRange(srcRange.getRow(), dstColumn, srcRichTextValues.length, srcRichTextValues[0].length).setRichTextValues(srcRichTextValues);
}
```

Comment: how can i specify the column to get range data in source sheet and column to recieve data in destination sheet

Comment: @Le Thanh Dat Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. About your additional request of `how can i specify the column to get range data in source sheet and column to recieve data in destination sheet`, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: thanks for adding the new one. Your english skill is not too bad

Comment: sorry for minding, but the added script just have the range of source column, which line of script contain the range of destination column

Comment: @Le Thanh Dat Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from `sorry for minding, but the added script just have the range of source column, which line of script contain the range of destination column`, I cannot understand what you want to do. Can I ask you about the details of your actual expected result? For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? I would like to modify my sample script by correctly understanding your actual expected result.

Comment: thanks for replying, example: i want import data in range column A ( A1:A ) into column range B (B1:B), just reply me if you still confuse

Comment: @Le Thanh Dat Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If that was not your expected result, I apologize again.

Comment: thanks for adding again, the hyperlink is clickable, but the text does not display the blue font and underline like the origin, just black text, can you understand my saying, feel free to reply

Comment: @Le Thanh Dat Thank you for replying. About `but the text does not display the blue font and underline like the origin, just black text`, I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script using your provided Spreadsheet, the values were copied with the hyperlink. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for my poor skill again. Can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Le Thanh Dat For example, in order to correctly replicate `but the text does not display the blue font and underline like the origin, just black text`, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including my proposed script for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it. And, I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: @Le Thanh Dat I have to apologize for my poor skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation of `but the text does not display the blue font and underline like the origin, just black text`. When I run my script using your provided spreadsheet, the values are copied by including the hyperlinks. I really apologize for my poor skill again. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including my proposed script for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it. And, I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.